# .Net Standard implementation resolution

Tags: .net-standard

There are lots of questions in SO and docs from MS about what is .net-Standard conceptually, what versions are implemented in what frameworks, how you can target and reference different .net-Stantard, .net-Core or .net-framework versions and what are the compatibility issues...

However I cannot find any good resources about how the full thing "works". I have downloaded the sources from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dotnet/standard), and it seems that it is all implemented like the following:

- All classes, structs and interfaces are declared as partial.
- All types have all the public members (ctors, methods and props) implemented as `throw null;`.
- All enums and constants are implemented in place with the expected values.

All of this makes a lot of sense, since .net-Standard does not implement anything (except obvious constants and enums which are expected to have the same values in all frameworks). But also you can use all this types and members by only targeting the .net-Standard appropriate version in your library.

However, partial classes must have all parts contained in the same assembly, and all of the parts must be declared as partial, and cannot implement the same members several times (also makes sense). Which makes me think that this is no regular compiler work happening here.

Imagine you have a .net-Core Console App, which references a .net-Standard library assembly, with some type that references the non-implemented .net-Standard DateTime struct. Obviously, the expected behaviour should be that the type used in runtime should be the DateTime implementation from .net-Core, but your assembly compiled using .net-Standard does not use that.

How does this works? I can reason two possible scenarios, none of which is ideal:

- The compiler re-compiles the .net-Standard assembly replacing all references with the proper .net-Core implementations, and actually uses this new assembly. This would mean that you cannot just take the .net-Standard assembly and "place it" besides to your .net-Core app assembly and make it work.
- There's some kind of run-time magic happening which replaces on the fly the types with the proper implementations. I doubt this would have good performance.

So, what am I missing here, how does this actually work? Can anyone provide any documentation where this is explained? (I am sure it exists, I just cannot find it).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime

Comment: Thanks for pointing out type forwarding, I didn't know about it and it definitely plays a role here.

Answer (score 1):

A explanation is provided in the video [.NET Standard - Under the Hood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg6nR7hS2lI&list=PLRAdsfhKI4OWx321A_pr-7HhRNk7wOLLY&index=4) which is referenced toward the end of the [.NET Standard FAQ](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md). More information is provided in the [.NET Standard 2.0 README](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md).

The answer is actually a combination of both scenarios you imagined - redirection to reference assemblies occurs at compile-time, and type forwarding to implementation assemblies occurs at runtime.

See also: [The how-dare-you-call-me-an-idiot’s guide to the .NET Standard](https://www.slideshare.net/citizenmatt/the-howdareyoucallmeanidiots-guide-to-the-net-standard-ndc-london-2017)